# Missing Parcelable CREATOR field?

Tags: android, parcelable, lint

My ResultReceiver subclass:

```
private class MyReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
    public MyReceiver() {
        super(null);
    }
    @Override 
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle data) {
        // yada yada
    }
}
```

Android Studio throws a wobbly about "Missing Parcelable CREATOR field". But you can see that my subclass doesn't any introduce any new members that would need to be packed into the Parcel. Is Android Studio being overly paranoid, or did I really need to implement a CREATOR field?

For now, I'm adding this:

```
@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
```

and the problem goes away, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: Can you provide the Parcelable class?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) is an interface. Classes that implement it (which MyReceiver does because it extends ResultReceiver) are expected to define the field CREATOR which can be used to unpack a new type of the given object from a Parcel.

Comment: I mean the class that implements Parcelable

Comment: Oh, that would be ResultReceiver which is an Android internal class. You can find it at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/777f5b2/core/java/android/os/ResultReceiver.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parcelable creators are typed to the specific class that's being serialized, so to be safe and complete, you should have a properly creator for every class that could be parceled.

Comment: Ahhh, so it's about the typing. So this implies that I could make lint happy by creating a CREATOR that does nothing but chain the superclass. Does this happen any time you subclass something that implements Parcelable? Maybe I've just gotten lucky until now.

Comment: I don't work with Parcelable very often, but I'm pretty sure that newer versions of Android Studio and the build tools get new checks and quick fixes all the time.  Studio is now really good about quick-fixing the warning about creators in classes that implement Parcelable with some stub code.

Comment: Yeah, I just switched from Eclipse to Studio, so I suspect that it's an old problem I'm hearing about for the first time. I'll have to see what Studio's quick fix does to my code. Thanks again.